# Complete eigen-vector basis from non invertible linear application

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

Consider a non-invertible linear application $O$ acting on a Hilbert space (quantum mechanics).

Is there still any chance to find a complete basis of $O$ eigen-vectors or no?

Comment: If such a basis exists, then the transformation must be normal.

Comment: Could I understand by your comment that there is still a chance to find such a basis?

Comment: The zero operator has a nice basis of eigenvectors, all with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: @TrialAndError WOW. Haha. This is the simple, trivial and right answer. How didn't I see it? Please put it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero operator has a nice basis of eigenvectors, all with the same eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

This will fail even in finite dimensions, and even without an inner product. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^4$, consider the operator
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}~.
$$
$A$ is in Jordan form, and has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, so in particular it is not invertible. Suppose $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$. That is, $Au = u$. Then $(A-I)u = 0$, i.e. writing $u = (x~y~z~w)^T$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\
z\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
That is, $y,z=0$ and $x,w$ can be any real number, so the $1$-eigenspace of $A$ is two-dimensional. But since the $0$-eigenspace is one-dimensional, it follows that the largest subspace you can span with eigenvectors is of dimension $3$. Therefore it is impossible to find a set of eigenvectors of $A$ that is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

---

Edit: On the other hand, here is an operator on $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a basis of eigenvectors:
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}~.
$$
Then the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a basis of eigenvectors.

In general, one needs more information about the Hilbert space and the operator $O$ to conclude anything about whether the eigenvectors of $O$ form a basis. Without any restrictions on $O$, either conclusion is possible.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question!

Comment: @aayyachi I believe it does, unless I have interpreted your question incorrectly. This is a Hilbert space ($\mathbb{R}^4$) and a non-invertible linear operator ($A$) acting on the Hilbert space such that no collection of its eigenvectors forms a basis for the Hilbert space.

Comment: @Lee Your example is not a proof that in general, we can or we can't find such a basis. I think you miss understood the question. Thanks

Comment: @aayyachi See the edit. The answer is that without more information, your question has no definite answer.

Comment: @Lee Ok. Does it mean, in general we can still hope to find such a basis? Right?

Comment: No. It means, *you need more information about your operator $O$.* You may very well have an operator such that it's impossible to find such a basis. Then again you may have an operator that has such a basis. *You must specify additional assumptions to guarantee that a basis of eigenvectors exists, and likewise additional assumptions to conclude that no such basis exists.*

Comment: @Lee I think you should improve your logic expressions. Thanks anyway.